# how to remove Mapping storage when tuple is used as input

Tags: ink, rust, storage, remove-all, mapping

Lets assume we have an ink! smart contract

On a vanilla Mapping

```
alpha: Mapping<[u8;32], Astruct>
```

we can use

```
self.alpha.remove(&somehash)
```

My question is this:
if we have the following mapping that takes a tuple

```
beta: Mapping<(String, [u8;20]) , Bstruct>
```

then we want to

```
self.beta.remove((&somestring, _))
```

Obviously the above does not and is not expected to work

Question: There are cases where for a given string in this case `somestring` as seen above for any value of the 2nd element of the tuple, we want to remove storage.
We understand that we can store in a Vec the 2nd tuple element values and then loop using

```
self.beta.remove((&somestring, &a1)) 
...
self.beta.remove((&somestring, &a1000000))
```

but we have been wondering if there is a better method to maybe reset the above beta Mapping to the default removing all storage for a specific 1st tupple element value.

For example `self.beta = Mapping::default();` would not be acceptable business logic

The concept of `self.beta.remove((&somestring, _))` makes business logic sense but is not acceptable

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that with the current existing technology, the above way of looping through the 2nd tuple element, is the acceptable solution.
Credits and many thanks to the Phala team for their support.